# How to get a clean descriptive statistics table that displays all variables grouped by outcomes of a categorical variable?

Tags: r, statistics, categorical-data, summary

The categorical variable I'm using has four possible outcomes (ResJobLocationChoice). I want to find the n observations, mean, standard deviation, and min/max for each outcome using multiple variables (categorical and continuous). Preferably in 1 table.

I've tried but I haven't been able to get it working with multiple variables.

```
with(data_df, table(Female, ResJobLocationChoice))
with(data_df, do.call(rbind, tapply(Wage, ResJobLocationChoice, function(x) c(Mean = mean(x), St.Dev. = sd(x)))))
```

I also tried using stargazer, but to no success:

```
data_df %>% 
  group_by(ResJobLocationChoice) %>% 
  stargazer(data_df[c("Wage","CommuteTime", "HousingPrice")], type="text", 
            digits=2, title="Residential-Job Location Choice")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no replication data available have used population data inbuilt in R. Create the table with summary stats and then use stargazer with summary = FALSE

```
population %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarise(amean=round(mean(population),2),
            asd=round(sd(population),2)) %>% 
stargazer(type = "text", summary=FALSE)
```

Comment: Can this be applied to multiple variables, categorical and continuous?
?

Comment: Can u be more specific regarding multiple variables? If you remove group by country , then mean and sd based on group will not be avaible. Instead overall mean and sd is estimated. eg using Cars93 dataset  Cars93%>% 
  group_by(Manufacturer) %>% 
  summarise(amean=round(mean(Price),2),
            asd=round(sd(Price),2))%>% 
  stargazer(type = "text", summary=FALSE)

Cars93%>% 
  
  summarise(amean=round(mean(Price),2),
            asd=round(sd(Price),2))%>% 
  stargazer(type = "text", summary=FALSE)

Comment: Okay I guess what I'm trying to ask is if can you only select/print only certain variable? I guess I could create a subset dataframe that only includes the most important variables I need, excluding irrelevant variables, but I was wondering if you could do that within this line of code. For the Cars93 example, say I group by Type and only want to display the summary information for Price and MPG.City, excluding the rest. So this returns in a table, the mean price and MPG.city for "Large" cars, price and MPG.city for "Compact" cars and so on.

Comment: Cars93%>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  summarise(meanprice=round(mean(Price),2), sdprice=round(sd(Price),2),
            meanMPG=round(mean(MPG.city),2), sdMPG=round(sd(MPG.city),2))%>%
  stargazer(type = "text", summary=FALSE)  . I think this would solve the problem.

Comment: The idea is to create a table and then add stargazer as a preferred style formatted table

Comment: This works! Thanks! Only issue is that the Types are represented by their factor number rather than their character value.